# React-Native run-android on specific device

Tags: react-native, adb

Is it possible to use the `run-android` command for one specific device only?

For example, if I have three devices (or emulators) connected and I want to use `run-android` on only one of them?

Maybe something like `adb install -s DEVICE_NUMBER`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Elaborating on @alexander 's answer, you can use the following workflow:

```
cd android
./gradlew assembleDebug # assembleRelease for release builds
adb install -s <yourdevice> app/build/outputs/apk/yourapk.apk # You can check the identifier for your device with adb devices
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 Will forward the phone's 8081 port to the computer's 8081, where the packager listens. If you are deploying over Wi-Fi, have a look at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-your-app-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi
```

In a different screen, run:

```
npm start # Will run the packager
```

If you really need this, you might want to wrap the first snippet into a script that you can parametrize with your phone's identifier.

Comment: Well okay, I knew about the "workaround" using ```adb install -s``` but I was curious if there was a similar way like ```react-native run-android -s```
But I think that answers my question. Thank you

Comment: just tiny fix: -s <device_name> goes before install. So: `adb -s <devices_name> install <project_dir>/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`

Answer (score 201):

To run react-native application on optional device you can specify some flags in run command. To see available add --help:

> npx react-native run-android --help

Then you can specify your device id throught --deviceId

> npx react-native run-android --deviceId=DEVICE_ID

To see available devices ids'

> adb devices

Comment: I'm using React Native 0.55.3 and when I add the `deviceId` parameter strange things happen. It seems to try to build a release version. I can see it bundling JS and assets and then it fails giving an error message related to key signing.

Comment: @RyanH. i also encounter release behavior when using it. Did you solve it?

Comment: @WantIt Sorry, no solution, just workarounds as I seldom develop with two Android devices. I simply connected one device at a time for the initial app install. After that, it's just a matter of shaking the device and hitting Reload in order to refresh JavaScript changes. As others are suggesting, you may need to build with gradle and install with `adb` if you want to keep multiple devices connected.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that `adb devices` return the simulators device ID just if they are currently open

Comment: This is useless because `adb devices` returns "The term 'adb' is not recognized...

Comment: @William dude, add adb to your path first.

Comment: What if I don't have open emulators?

Comment: this should be the accepted anwser

Answer (score 54):

**To list AVDs:**

`$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -list-avds`

**To run a specific emulator:**

`$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd Pixel_API_28_AOSP`

**To run React Native in the currently-open emulator:**

`npx react-native run-android`

**To choose between multiple running emulators:**

```
adb devices
npx react-native run-android --deviceId=DEVICE_ID
```

(Last point from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49996656/152711))

Comment: What if my i am running my app on my real device(not on emulator) which is connected to a local port without usb. Then in that case how should i run it without connecting the usb

Comment: It says:
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.

Comment: Worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 16):

```
npx react-native run-android --deviceId='myDeviceId'
```

This works for me. don't forget `''` this one. it accepts string

Comment: Actually you don't need ''

Answer (score 10):

You can do `npx react-native run-android --list-devices`. This will allow you to select a device/emulator among the available ones (connected as well as disconnected).

Answer (score 3):

May be we can not select which android device attached to run.

Read from official react native website:

[You must have only one device connected at a time.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)

Comment: This restriction does not apply any more, the `--deviceId` option mentioned in @nerius-jok's answer should work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `run-android` command to start it on specific device

Firstly, you have to start the packager:

```
./packager/packager.sh
```

Then just build an APK file and run it on target device. APK will connect to the build server, and fetch bundle from it automatically.

But if it didn't happen by some reasons, click on reload button :-)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, first of all, be sure about `adb` installation which I think while setting up your RN environment you have it for sure, follow these steps:

1. Connect your Android external device to your computer with a cable
2. Run this command `adb devices` and you will see the result at least:

   ```
   List of devices attached
   9999xxx3434yyy  device
   ```

   **FYI**: *the* `9999xxx3434yyy` *is your device id*
3. Put the given device id in the following command

   ```
   npx react-native run-android --deviceId="9999xxx3434yyy"
   ```

   or

   ```
   yarn run react-native run-android --deviceId="9999xxx3434yyy"
   ```

**HINT**: If the device is a Xiaomi product keep watching the phone screen because you should grand install access.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using React >= 0.68.x. Just type this:

```
npx react-native run-android --deviceId=VCR4XCORPFTKAQFA
```

VCR4XCORPFTKAQFA is recovered typing adb devices in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To run the app on one specific connected android device:

1. Disconnect/Unplug all connected android devices.
2. Connect/Plug the device you want to install the app in
3. Run `adb devices` on your terminal to see the list connected devices (you should only see 1 such device as rest were disconnected)
4. Run `npx react-native run-android`

This will install the React-native app on the connected device via usb.

Answer (score 0):

### When 2 or more devices are connected

There seem to be no way to install app on a specific device in this scenario. So follow this

1. Disconnect all devices except one
2. run the command, in my case its `npx react-native run-android`
3. Now connect another device
4. repeat 2nd point
5. when done with every device, connect all and see device ids `adb devices`
6. now map device's port `8081` to computer's `8081`

Eg:

```
 adb -s DEV_1_ID reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
 adb -s DEV_2_ID reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
 adb -s DEV_3_ID reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
 ...
```