# How could I launch the application without using "expo and emulator"

Tags: react-native

[image: Screenshot of commands and error message]

**[1-npm install -g react-native-cli ]**

create new project command
**react-native init MyAwesome **

run project
**cd MyAwesome**

connect my cellphone via laptop "developer mode and  USB debugging mode is on also"
**react-native run-android**

```
C:\Users\ALL INDIA\Desktop\expMng> react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:9536) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
'C:\Users\ALL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725219/react-native-run-android-on-specific-device

Answer (score 0):

You should set it with C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x.

> \bin is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Your android studio is not set up correctly.
Follow this to set the environment variable for android studio
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
and do restart your PC after setup and give it a try